# How to create Smart Device application using VS2010

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, mobile-application

I am new to Mobile App developemnt and from what i gather in VS2008 you could create a Smart Device application. It VS2010 that option is not available. MSDN points to Win7 using Silverlight. Is there other options to creating Smart Device Apps or Android apps? I'm using VS2010 professional edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to use your existing Visual Studio/.NET knowledge to build applications for other platforms, you might want to take a look at Mono.  Mono is a wrapper for the native SDKs, and is available for both iOS and Android so you can develop proper native apps for these platforms, while still using Visual Studio.

- [Mono Android](http://android.xamarin.com/)
- [Monotouch (iOS)](http://xamarin.com/monotouch)

HTH

Comment: Thank you. In conjuction with your answer, I can also conigure Asp.Net Webform or MVC for Mobile Apps?

Comment: This does indeed work with Visual Studio, however using other development technologies such as [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or writing native is a better solution.

Comment: Mono is a technology that allows you to write an app that is still native, but in a different language.  It still uses the native SDK and compiles into native code.  It reuses .NET programming skill without going so far as to create a single cross-platform binary.  I would argue that Appcelerator is a cheap alternative to a native app and the results are far from as good.